# Php, sum and average values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array wherein I need to return the average of the "price" & "perUnitVolume" and the sum of the "qty" WHERE the Year & Month match. For example in this array, 2 elements in the array have Year = 2014 & Month = 11, these elements need to be summed and averaged. This is a simplified output of my array (actual array has > 1000 elements in the array, many variations of Year and Month), just don't know how to get the results that I need using php.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [asin] => XXXXXX
        [price] => 19.99
        [qtyTotal] => 22
        [perUnitVolume] => 0.22
        [Month] => 2014
        [Year] => 11
        [Day] => 14
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [asin] => YYYYYYY
        [price] => 24.99
        [qtyTotal] => 53
        [perUnitVolume] => 0.54
        [Month] => 2014
        [Year] => 11
        [Day] => 15
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [asin] => XXXXXX
        [price] => 19.99
        [qtyTotal] => 13
        [perUnitVolume] => 0.99
        [Month] => 2015
        [Year] => 08
        [Day] => 16
    )
)
```

Basically in the end I need to end up with this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [asin] => XXXXXX
        [price] => 22.49 (average of 19.99 + 24.99 / 2)
        [qtyTotal] => 75 (sum of 22 + 53)
        [perUnitVolume] => 0.38 (average of 0.22 + 0.54 / 2)
        [Month] => 2014
        [Year] => 11
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [asin] => YYYYYYY
        [price] => 19.99
        [qtyTotal] => 53
        [perUnitVolume] => 0.54
        [Month] => 2015
        [Year] => 08
    )
 )
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and what problems you've run into?

Comment: Is this coming from a database?  Much easier.

Comment: I posted this on stack, but didn't get any answers so I thought I would try it using an array and still encountered issues beyond my pay grade :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096403/mysql-get-average-and-sum-of-columns-and-group-by-year-month ... I would've deleted my original post but I feel that both issues are beneficial to the Stack community if answers can be found.